# Проблемы с производительностью yii2

Tags: веб-программирование, yii2, сервер, yii, веб-сервер

Здравствуйте, такая проблема, две одинаковые страницы с одним запросом к базе данных.
Один скрин сделан на сервере другой на локалке, почему такая колоссальная разница в потреблении памяти??
Меня не устраивает что на сервере 9МВ
Всем кто поможет огромное спасибо!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да вообще, все те двиги, которые построенные на данных фреймворках - это ресурсоемко (как минимум) - объекты занимают больше памяти, чем хотелось бы (чем нативные массивы и функции например). То, сколько плодят классов и объектов, а потом удивляются, а чтож так жрет то.

Comment: @And так почему тогда на локалке столько не жрет? я понимаю еслиб было одинаково, меня бы это не напрягало, а так....

Comment: Это может влиять на задержки к примеру. А вобоще, смотрите больше логов, где утечка памяти и в каком месте столько жрет.

Comment: @And как это можно исправить?

Comment: Проводите тесты, и показывайте логи. желательно также минимальный код, который вы написали и думаете, что он много сжирает памяти.

Comment: @And так в том и дело что там кода то практически нет

Comment: ну так и показывайте, то. что есть.

Comment: @Ricco381 можно посмотреть потребление памяти с помощью xhprof. Поставьте его, запустите, сравните что получилось. PS. Какие версии PHP там и там?

Comment: @TotalPusher  Спасибо всем, сам дал ответ, может кому помогу

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу сам.
Всем у кого будет такая беда, смотрите на модули которые подключены у вас на локалке и сервере, у меня в данной ситуации не был подключен

> opcache

По этому и была такая огромная разница, как только подключил все стола на свои места!
Всем кому помог, я буду очень рад;)